# Non-blocking transactions when reading from ActiveMQ queue with STOMP

Tags: php, transactions, activemq-classic, nonblocking, stomp

I'm interacting with ActiveMQ via STOMP. I have one process which publishes messages and a multiple processes that subscribes and processes the messages (about 10 parallel instances).

After reading a message I want to be sure that if, for some reason my application fails/crashes, the message will not be lost. So naturally, I turned to transactions. Unfortunately, I discovered that once a consumer reads a message as a part of the transaction, all the following messages are not being sent to the other consumers, until the transaction ends.

Test case: `abc` queue has a 100 messages. If I activate the following code in two different browser tabs, the first will return in 10 seconds and the second will return in 20 seconds.

```
<?php
// Reader.php
$con = new Stomp("tcp://localhost:61613");
$con->connect();

$con->subscribe(
    "/queue/abc",
    array()
);

$tx = "tx3".microtime();
echo "TX:$tx<BR>";
$con->begin($tx);
$messages = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $t = microtime(true);
    $msg = $con->readFrame();
    if (!$msg) {
        die("FAILED!");
    }
    $t = microtime(true)-$t; echo "readFrame() took $t MS to complete<BR>";
    array_push($messages, $msg);
    $con->ack($msg, $tx);
    sleep(1);
}
$con->abort($tx);
```

Is there something I'm missing code-wise? Is there a way to configure ActiveMQ (or send a header) that will make the transaction remove the item from the queue, allow other processes consume the other messages, and if the transaction fails or is timed-out, will put the item back in?

PS: I thought about creating another queue - DetentionQueue for each reading process but I really rather not do it if I have a choice.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to adjust the prefetch size of the subscription so that ActiveMQ doesn't send the Messages on the Queue to client 1 before client 2 gets a chance to get any.  By default its set to 1000 so best to tune it for your use case.

You can set the prefetch size via the "activemq.prefetchSize=1" header on the subscribe frame.  Refer to the [ActiveMQ Stomp](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html) page for all the frame options.

Comment: I my specific ActiveMQ version the default prefetch size was 1 (checked against AvctiveMQ console). Just to be sure, I checked your suggestion (using activemq.prefetchSize=1) but it did not change the outcome.
But thanks, anyway :)